# new Date("05-MAY-09 03.55.50") is any thing wrong with this ? i am getting illegalArgumentException

Tags: java

```
new Date("05-MAY-09 03.55.50")
```

is any thing wrong with this ? i am getting illegalArgumentException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use this method, as it has been deprecated for years (and years).  Use DateFormat.parse() in which you can easily define the format you want to parse.

Answer (score 14):

That [Date constructor is deprecated](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date(java.lang.String)) for a reason.

You should be using a [DateFormat](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) / [SimpleDateFormat](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) instead to create Date instances from a String representation.

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss");
Date myDate = df.parse("05-05-MAY-09 03.55.50");
```

This way, you can parse dates that are in just about any format you could conceivably want.

Answer (score 2):

Other than the fact that you are using a deprecated method (you should be using [SimpleDateFormat](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) instead), this should work:

```
    new Date("05-MAY-09 03:55:50");
```

Also check out [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: And the Joda Time requrement has been fulfilled! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/835418/what-are-the-stackoverflow-standard-answers-closed

Answer (score 1):

Use colons to separate hours, minutes and seconds: "05-MAY-09 03:55:50"

Answer (score 0):

That constructor is deprecated (since jdk 1.1).

It not even valid in java5

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html

You should

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
Date date = sdf.parse("05-MAY-09 03:55:50");
```

Comment: Unless you meant this as pseudo-code, it won't compile since parse() is not a static method

Comment: yes, i meant pseudocode. As shown in http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html